# Saving argument that comes before the flag

Tags: bash

In bash shell scripting, I'm trying to take the argument that comes before the flag.

When the argument comes after the flag, I know that I could use getopts and have the case smth like `echo "there's an -g flag! Argument: $OPTARG`

However I have no clue how to take an argument that comes before the flag. Let's say I would like to process this command: `./filename 2345 -g`.

And the argument is a PID that the flag is trying to take argument as.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless you also support `./filename -g 2345`, this is probably a convention you shouldn't try to support. And if you *do* also support `-g 2345`, then there's an easy answer -- to separate your options and positional arguments into two different data structures.

Comment: BTW, `getopts` is not actually a best-practices solution. See [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Assuming Best Practices

Let's say your `-g` stands for `global`, and that you support passing `-g` either before *or* after the number whose meaning it changes. A mostly-conventional parser (not compliant with baseline POSIX conventions only inasmuch as the latter require all options to come before any positional arguments) might look a bit like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

args=( )
global=0
while (( $# )); do
  case $1 in
    -g) global=1 ;;
    --) shift; args+=( "$@" ); break ;;
    -*) echo "Unrecognized argument $1" >&2; exit 1 ;;
    *)  args+=( "$1" ) ;;
  esac
  shift
done

if (( global )); then
  echo "Doing something with global PID ${args[0]}"
fi
```

That is to say: Store your positional arguments in a separate location (in this case, the `args` array), and refer back to them as-needed.

---

#### Real, Literal (Awful) Answer

If you really want to store your last argument in a variable and refer back to that variable when you see `-g`, of course, you *can* do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

last_arg=
while (( $# )); do
  case $1 in
    -g) global=$last_arg ;;
  esac
  last_args=$1
  shift
done

if [[ $global ]]; then
  echo "Global value is $global"
fi
```

...however: **Don't**. This violates both POSIX and GNU command-line utility conventions, and thus will be surprising to any of your users who are long-time UNIX users.